# Newly Created route not reflected to production server

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2

Our production server is hosted on AWS.I have created a new route and defined the template for that.It is working in my local system but when I pushed it to production server is not working,showing that "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.".We figured it out and run a command(php artisan route:list) on production server,this is not showing the newly added route but when I ran this command to local system,I found this route.So,my question is why is it not showing on production server ie this not reflected to there.

web.php

```
<?php

    //RegisterController
    Route::get('/ent-register','RegisterController@entrepreneur');
    Route::get('/org-register','RegisterController@organization');
    Route::get('/sup-register','RegisterController@supporter');
    Route::get('/inv-register','RegisterController@investor');
    Route::post('/register/store','RegisterController@store');
    Route::get('/reg-note','RegisterController@reg_note');
    Route::get('/contact-note','RegisterController@contact_note');//this is the newly added route
?>
```

contact-note.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title','Request response')
@section('pagebody')

<!-- Start Inner Contents -->

    <section class="myaccount-header">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div>
    </section>

    <section class="myaccount-body">
    <div class="myaccount-document">
    <div class="container">
    <!--<p>We are submitted your request to the AIM administrator, They will response your request as soon as possible.<a href="{{url('/')}}" target="_top">Go Back To Home Page</a></p>-->

    <p>Thank you for contacting us, our team will get back to you shortly. <a href="{{url('/')}}" target="_top">Go Back To Home Page</a></p>
    <!-- AddThis Sharing Buttons below -->                  </div>
    </div>
    </section>

@endsection
```

RegisterController.php

```
public function contact_note()
{
    return view('home.contact-note');
}
```

Comment: show you web.php file or route:list logs. So that others can help you :)

Comment: Are you caching the routes on your production server?  Try clearing or re-caching the routes there https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#route-caching

Comment: Thank you @Gareth Drew,this command "php artisan route:cache" solved my problem.